# Magento 2: Product collection with filters

Tags: magento2, product-collection

Can anyone tell me how can i get product collection with filters?
I'm use magento 2 sample data now. So i'm trying to get in product collection like selected on picture
[image]
with attribure style=backpack and activity=yoga; 
My code:

```
$productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('style_bags','activity')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array('attribute'=>'style_bags','eq'=>24),
                array('attribute'=>'activity','eq'=>8)
            )
        );
```

echo $productcollection->count();

But i'm get 4 products instead 2. But if i'll live only

> array('attribute'=>'style_bags','eq'=>24)

without

> array('attribute'=>'activity','eq'=>8)

it will works correct.

Can anyoune explain me how it works?
Thank you.

**UPD:** It's seems to me, that in that case products selects with OR condition. But i need AND. If i change my code to

```
$productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('style_bags','activity')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('style_bags',['eq'=>24])
            ->addAttributeToFilter('activity',['eq'=>8]);
```

I'ce got emty set.

Answer (score 10):

1) We can print the sql with `getSelect()`

```
echo $productcollection->getSelect();
```

2) Add attribute filter to collection `vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection::addAttributeToFilter()`:

If `$attribute` is an array, it will add OR condition with the following format:

```
 array(
     array('attribute'=>'firstname', 'like'=>'test%'),
     array('attribute'=>'lastname', 'like'=>'test%'),
  )
```

vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection::addAttributeToFilter()

```
    if (is_array($attribute)) {
        $sqlArr = [];
        foreach ($attribute as $condition) {
            $sqlArr[] = $this->_getAttributeConditionSql($condition['attribute'], $condition, $joinType);
        }
        $conditionSql = '(' . implode(') OR (', $sqlArr) . ')';
```

So, as you said, your fist case will add OR condition.

There is a note when adding Eav attribute filter to collection. Take a look `eav_attribute` table, we can select `color` attribute:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute e WHERE e.attribute_code = 'color';
```

- `backend_type` is `int` - We can find the values in `catalog_product_entity_int` table. We use the values in our collection.
- `frontend_input` is `select` - The value of this field to set type of frontend field type.

  ```
  $collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
  $productcollection =
      $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addAttributeToFilter(
                  [
                      //['attribute'=>'type_id','neq'=> 'simple'],
                      ['attribute'=>'color','eq'=> 4] // Color filter
                  ]
              );


  echo $productcollection->getSelect();
  ```

In your case, you should check the `backend_type` again.

3) You also can try with the Service Contracts Layer

Your construct:

```
 protected $_productRepository;

protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
) {
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
}
```

In your custom method:

```
$searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('color', 4, 'eq')->create();
$searchResults = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
$products = $searchResults->getItems();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use Search Criteria for filter collections.
It is better way (and correct) to filter collections in Magento2.
Go to http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories/ and search for "Search Criteria" section ;)

It is not so hard to use it.

Comment: i tried, but it's not work. Still empty set result when i try to add style_bags AND acivity filters.

Comment: How have you tried it? are you sure that those attributes are saved property in products?

Answer (score 3):

My answer is based on Konrad Siamro's answer and http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories/

Here's what I do and it seems to be working:

```
<?php
namespace Company\ModName\Model;

class Helper
{
    protected $pageRepository;
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $filterBuilder;
    protected $filterGroupBuilder;
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $_productAttributeRepository;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Cms\Model\PageRepository $pageRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository
    )
    {
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->filterGroupBuilder = $filterGroupBuilder;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
    }

    private function returnProdCollectBasedOnYearAndMake($yearOptionCode, $makeOptionCode)
    {
        $yearOptionId = $this->getOptionId('year', $yearOptionCode);
        $makeOptionId = $this->getOptionId('make', $makeOptionCode);

        $filter_1 = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('make')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->setValue($makeOptionId)
            ->create();

        $filter_2 = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('year')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->setValue($yearOptionId)
            ->create();

        $filter_group_1 = $this->filterGroupBuilder
            ->addFilter($filter_1)
            ->create();

        $filter_group_2 = $this->filterGroupBuilder
            ->addFilter($filter_2)
            ->create();

        $search_criteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->setFilterGroups([$filter_group_1, $filter_group_2])
            ->create();

        $repo = $this->productRepository;
        $result = $repo->getList($search_criteria);
        $products = $result->getItems();
        foreach($products as $product)
        {
            echo $product->getSku() . "<br>";
        }

        return $products;
    }

    private function getOptionId($attributeCode, $optionLabel)
    {
        $options = $this->_productAttributeRepository->get($attributeCode)->getOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($optionLabel === $option->getLabel()) {
                return $option->getValue();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything here an only the solution below worked for me:

```php
$prodColl = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $prodColl->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                       ->addAttributeToFilter('activity', ['eq'=>'8'])
                       ->load();

echo '<pre>'; print_r($collection->getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer.php`

Line No - 149 
Add your custom code 
`$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name','Adrienne Trek Jacket');`

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php` 
Line No - 150
Add your custom code
`$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name','Adrienne Trek Jacket');`

As both are public method you can create plugins for same

[image]