# How to get product by custom attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

I want get product by custom attribute

My code :

```
protected $product;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
)
{
    $this->product = $product;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}
$productId = $this->product->loadByAttribute('ean', 123456);
```

or

```
$productId = $this->product->loadByAttribute('price', 100);
```

Example : Get id product by price, ean, color ...

Please help me, thanks all

Comment: Can you please explain what's issue in this code?

Comment: Hi Rohan Hapani, i want load product or get id product by price or ean

Comment: check it with : echo $productId->getId() for product id and print_r($productId->getData()); for product load.

Comment: please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279680/how-to-display-attribute-value-in-magento-2-using-getproducts-method

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to take a look at collections in Magento 2. You can create a filter that you can use on the collection to filter the products you need based on your (custom) attributes. The collection contains the products you need, like in your example all products who has a specific color or a product with a specific ean.

Have a look at the following link;

[Magento 2: Product collection with filters](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164252/magento-2-product-collection-with-filters/164265)